# How to reference values from one Vec to another?

Tags: rust, vector

I'm just trying to make something like this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut points: Vec<(&str, &str)> = Vec::new();
    let existing: Vec<(String, String)> = Vec::new();

    for t in existing {
        points.push((&t.0[..], &t.1[..]));
    }
}
```

And got an error:

```
error[E0597]: `t.0` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:6:23
  |
5 |     for t in existing {
  |         - binding `t` declared here
6 |         points.push((&t.0[..], &t.1[..]));
  |         ------        ^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
  |         |
  |         borrow later used here
7 |     }
  |     - `t.0` dropped here while still borrowed
```

How could I do this in Rust?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lifetimes start at the variable declaration. Since your `points` variable is created before the `existing` variable, `points` is not allowed to have any references to `existing`, because `existing` will be dropped before `points`.

The second issue is that you are iterating over values, which will further limit the lifetime of the Strings to the loop-body.

The easy solution is to swap the two declarations and change the loop to iterate over references instead of values:

```
let existing : Vec<(String, String)> = Vec::new();
let mut points : Vec<(&str, &str)> = Vec::new();

for t in &existing {
    points.push((&t.0, &t.1));
}
```